# R GGPLOT2 Multiple Lines with same Y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I've been struggling with ggplot in r. I'm trying to create a line graph with three variables plotted onto it - small saplings, medium saplings and large saplings. The X axis will be 'mean number of saplings' and the Y axis should be 'bird species richness'.

Here is an extract:

```
birdspp smallsaplings   mediumsaplings  largesaplings
95      5.044642857     2.384615385     1.30952381
97      3.482269504     1.873684211     1.390625
63      6.285714286     2               2.4
57      5.216216216     1.666666667     1.125
```

My problem is, I can't for the life of me work out how to plot all three lines on one graph!

I have tried two approaches. The traditional hopeful way...

```r
 ggplot(data, aes(y=birdspp, x=saplings)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = smallsaplings, colour = "blue"))+
  geom_point(aes(x = smallsaplings, colour = "blue")) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = mediumsaplings, colour = "green")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = mediumsaplings, colour = "green")) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = largesaplings, colour = "red")) +
  geom_point(aes(x = largesaplings, colour = "red"))
```

[which produces this monstrosity :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVxgL.png)

and using a melt function from the reshape library...

```
mdf <- melt(mdf, id.vars="Sapplings", value.name="value", variable.name="birdspp")
ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=Sapplings, y=value, group = birdspp, colour = birdspp)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
```

Apologies if the error is blindingly obvious, I'm a newbie.

Comment: One issue is `x=saplings` in your main call to ggplot. This column doesn't exist in your data. Also the plot will be much easier if you convert you data to "long" format. Something like this: `library(reshape2); ggplot(melt(data, id.var="birdspp"), aes(x=value, y=birdspp, colour=variable)) + geom_line() + geom_point()`.

Comment: With your original approach, each line could be plotted similarly to this: `ggplot(data, aes(y=birdspp)) + geom_line(aes(x=smallsaplings), colour="blue")`.

Comment: I'm getting close! Graph is here, I am just struggling with the line of best fit. geom_line just links up all the points and ideally I'd want geom_abline but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `geom_smooth(method="lm")`

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic "wide to long" problem. It's easier if you tidy the data first, so it has one column with sapling type and another with the mean numbers.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  gather(sapling_type, mean_number, -birdspp)
```

Now you can pipe that into `ggpplot` and colour by sapling type. I'm not sure about lines though. Maybe start with points first.

```
df1 %>% 
  gather(sapling_type, mean_number, -birdspp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mean_number, birdspp)) + geom_point(aes(color = sapling_type))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great, I have the graph now and am just struggling with the line of best fit. Geom_line or geom_abline aren't being nice with this one. Will let you know if I figure it out!

Comment: Do you want a line per group (sapling type) or a line through all the points?

Comment: Per sapling type. The biology behind this one is just showing that saplings don't change species richness in fragmented forests. Quite interesting stuff. They seem to be more effected by tree circumference (so age of forest) if you're interested!

Comment: You can fit and plot linear models in `ggplot2`. Try adding this to the end of the second code example in the answer: `+ geom_smooth(aes(group = sapling_type, color = sapling_type), method = "lm")`.

Comment: No such luck I'm afraid

Comment: My mistake, that does work! Thank you for your help.